# How can I subtract 2 operations in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to calculate the lower_limit out of an object called management_fee, In order to calculate this variable, I need to get the average of management_fee, then I need to get the Standard Deviation. Once I have calculated both variables, I can subtract the average minus the Standard deviation.

This is an example of the JSO that I am currently working on:

```
{
        "_id": "5d44ef5ea366bfcdc21",
        "user": "5d2f594faa4182c47c",
        "management_fee": 399,
        "cancellation_date": "2017-05-02T00:00:00.000Z",
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "Texas",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
    "_id": "5d44ef5ea366bfcdc22",
        "user": "5d2f594faa4182c42c",
        "management_fee": 599,
        "cancellation_date": "2017-08-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "Texas",
        "__v": 0
    },
   {
    "_id": "5d44ef5ea366bfcdc23",
        "user": "5d2f594faa4182c48c",
        "management_fee": 700,
        "cancellation_date": "2017-08-09T00:00:00.000Z",
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "New York",
        "__v": 0
    }
```

In the code below, I want to group the lower_limit by year, and then calculate this by doing an average and Deviation Standard of management_fee, so I can then subtract both.

```
    router.get('/random_test_10', auth, async (req, res) => {

      try {

        const model_CancellationKPI = await CancellationKPI.aggregate([
          {
            $group: {
              _id: {year:{$year: "$cancellation_date"}},
              lower_limit: {$subtract:[ {std:{$stdDevSamp: "$management_fee"}, avr:{$avg:"$management_fee"}}]}, 

            }
          }
        ])

       res.json(model_CancellationKPI);

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message); 
        res.status(500).send('Server Error')
      }

    });
```

The answer provided below worked fine. But, now I want to add the total and average in the same output, but I receive null and 0. Do you know why?

This is my code:

```
router.get('/random_test_11', auth, async (req, res) => {

      try {

        const model_CancellationKPI = await CancellationKPI.aggregate([{
          $group: {
              _id: { year: { $year: "$cancellation_date" } }, 
              std: { $stdDevSamp: '$management_fee' }, avg: { $avg: '$management_fee' }
          }}, 

          { $project: { year: '$_id.year', _id: 0, 
          result: { $subtract: ['$avg', '$std'] }, average: {$avg: '$management_fee'}, 
          total: {$sum: '$management_fee}'}
          } }])


       res.json(model_CancellationKPI);

      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message); 
        res.status(500).send('Server Error')
      }

    });
```

And this is the output:

```
[
    {
        "year": 2017,
        "result": 388.90493206697874,
        "average": null,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "year": 2019,
        "result": 88.03232361610253,
        "average": null,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "year": 2018,
        "result": 367.4573075192308,
        "average": null,
        "total": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
db.getCollection('CancellationKPI').aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: { year: { $year: "$cancellation_date" } }, std: { $stdDevSamp: '$management_fee' },total :{$sum :'$management_fee'}, average: { $avg: '$management_fee' }
    }
}, { $project: { year: '$_id.year', _id: 0, average: 1, total: 1, result: { $subtract: ['$average', '$std'] } } }])
```

Comment: Thanks @srinivasy. Can you explain the error above?

Comment: @ManfredTijerino : Updated my answer with your new req, Please check now. Issue with your code is, you're trying to do operation on non-existing field 'management_fee' in $project stage, instead you could do that in group and project in final result.

Comment: Thank you so much @srinivasy. It worked well. I have a question, why did you put the following on your code:  average: 1, total:1. What is the logic behind?

Comment: @ManfredTijerino : That's to include those needed fields in o/p, unless you do that in $project it would not persist those values in documents (If we don't do that for those fields we'll only see year & result in the response) !! $project is just a kind of wrapper for the response. you need to mention all the fields to be included or else to be excluded.

Comment: is there a way to do this purely manipulating the json with JavaScript? if so, I kindly appreciate your support by providing an example.

Comment: @ManfredTijerino : Do you mean excluding fields from the output, wanted to do it in js ?

Comment: The reason, why I am asking is because. In this case this data come from a Mongo's database. But, what if I have access to api, and I need to retrieve this data. I cannot use aggregate, since this is Mongo's instance. In theory, it should be done by manipulating the json using JS.

Comment: @ManfredTijerino : ok that case you need to iterate through result and delete the needed fields from each object using delete of Javascript, I can help you more if you can provide more examples maybe raise a new question with needed info like input data and required output.. basically check two things how to iterate thru json array and second delete a field in json object Javascript

Comment: Hi @srinivasy, is there a way to do this aggregate in MongoDB?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57740563/how-can-i-sum-total-of-cancellation-per-month-grouped-by-years-in-mongodb

Comment: @ManfredTijerino  I'm on vacation will sure look into it if it's not answered by the time I return tomorrow

Comment: hi @srinivasy, did you have the chance to take a look at the question? I am really stuck over that solution.

Comment: @ManfredTijerino : I've tried but not able to get it, it has many things in it, maybe it would be easy if you can achieve it thru code, I'm trying on it, if I can get it will post it there..

Comment: I really appreciate your support @srinivasy. Any idea of how to get this one, it will definitely help me out.

Comment: Not sure, I tried till the part of grouping based on year & month & even converted month in numbers to month as names but got struck where you need month and totalAmount as key + value pair, not getting anything from there..

Comment: Probably doing it by manipulating the JSON with JavaScript, instead of doing it with MongoDB's queries.